# (iOS) Firestore document snapshotListener stops working 1 hour after signing in

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I implemented firebase/auth and use that to sign into firebase using a custom token that I get from our API.

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withCustomToken: result.data.token) { (authResult, error) in
    completion(authResult != nil && error == nil)
}
```

Then I subscribe to my document using a snapshotListener.

```
guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
    return
}

listListener = firestoreDB.collection(shoppingListCollectionName).document(user.uid).addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, _) in ....
```

The listener works for roughly 1 hour and then it stops working. In the logs I get:

> Stream error: 'Unauthenticated: Missing or invalid authentication.'

And then I get spammed with:

> Stream error: 'Unknown: An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.'

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much the about custom token as you are using custom token to authenticate. But if we are coming to the firebase authentication, the id token issued by firebase has a lifespan of a maximum of one hour. After that the firebase will issue a new id token using the refresh token. I think your id token is getting expired and it is not getting issued again.

Comment: Any idea about why it might not be re-issued? Our Android developer doesn't have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase ID tokens last for only one hour. As you are using a custom token, if you want stay authenticated beyond one hour you will need to use the [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth). So you will have to make an HTTP request to get an ID token and a refresh token from your custom token (check the [Exchange custom token for an ID and refresh token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-verify-custom-token) section). Then, you will just have to refresh the ID token every time it expires (check the [Exchange a refresh token for an ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-refresh-token) section).